# Arduino: for loop not working inside of while loop

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a set of LEDs 12 in total: 6 are blue, 6 are red. I had for loops that helped with the clutter for turning the LEDs on and off at a set interval. But now I want to make it so it has while loops controlling how long until the LED's speed changes. I have made 2 so far and both of them work but the second I put the for loop inside it doesn't do anything.

```
int redLEDPins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
int blueLEDPins[] = {8,9,10,11,12,13};
int LED_Amount = 6;
int led_delay = 1000;

unsigned long time_since_last_reset = 0;
int wail = 5000;
int yelp = 3000;
int phaser = 3000;
int hilo = 3000;

void setup() {
  for (int i; i < LED_Amount; i++) {
    pinMode(redLEDPins[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(blueLEDPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //wail while loop
  time_since_last_reset = millis();
  while((millis() - time_since_last_reset) < wail) {
    led_delay = 250;
    Serial.print("delay: ");
    Serial.println(led_delay);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(500);
  }

  //yelp while loop
  time_since_last_reset = millis();
  while((millis() - time_since_last_reset) < wail){
    led_delay = 50;
    Serial.print("delay: ");
    Serial.println(led_delay);
    for (int i; i < LED_Amount; i++) {
      digitalWrite(redLEDPins[i], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(blueLEDPins[i], LOW);
      Serial.println("Red on ");
      Serial.println("Blue off");
    }
    delay(led_delay);
    for (int i; i < LED_Amount; i++){
    digitalWrite(redLEDPins[i], LOW);
    digitalWrite(blueLEDPins[i], HIGH);
    Serial.println("Red off ");
    Serial.println("Blue on");
    }
    delay(led_delay);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (**int i**; i < LED_Amount; i++){
  digitalWrite(redLEDPins[i],LOW);
  digitalWrite(blueLEDPins[i],HIGH);
  Serial.println("Red off ");
  Serial.println("Blue on");
}
```

Might that be because you didn't initialize i?

Comment: just tried this and it threw a compile error

    expected primary-expression before 'int'

Comment: `for (int i = 0;`